# Sum numbers in row of text file (linux command terminal)

Tags: linux, bash

Say i have the numbers 6 1 4 in that format, what would be the best way to sum them so that i get the result 11 in the command terminal in linux using bash?

Comment: how about google a bit ?

Comment: check for `bc` in google. If that does not help , please share more details about your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Line Answer :

```
$echo "6 4 1" | awk '{print $1+$2+$3}'
11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bc`

```
a=6; b=4; c=1;
echo "$a+$b+$c" | bc
```

Output-
`11`

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, it would be straight forward:

```
awk '{tot=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) tot+=$i; print tot}' filename
```

But if you prefer bash-only then you can use a loop:

```
while read -r line; do 
   tot=0
   for val in $line; do
      ((tot+=val))
   done
   echo $tot
done < filename
```

If the numbers in the file are float then you can use `bc` or `dc` as bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic.